# Need to use Encrypted Authorization code from http response & use it further in the code

Tags: encryption, cookies, decryption, parameters, jmeter

I want to decrypt the below field "_id" from HTTP Request/Response (present in both) , parameterize it & use in my scripts below -

set-cookie: **_id=s%3AYBcRSbGD5DPTGRQUjNhVK5Het9UtX74ZfjA855eusWBWWlZ592hgwxfO8aJBkjf8.fFdLCCR67o63%2B8%2Btxw0TLhgLSVyJMhpxAzl0flGXc2Q**; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure

Is there a way to decrypt this in jmeter ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to "decrypt" it, [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) work as follows:

1. Server sends a piece of information via [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header
2. Browser stores the cookies internally
3. On next request if the target URL matches the cookie hostname and path and the cookie is not expired the browser sends the value in [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

So it's sufficient to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) to your test plan and it will automatically handle your `_id` cookie (as well as other cookies)

If you need to store the cookie value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to use it somewhere else - you can add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

and once you restart JMeter it will store the `_id` cookie into `${COOKIE__id}` JMeter Variable and you will be able to use it where required.